# Count each character in string using recursion

Tags: javascript, string, object

i have tried to make a function count each character in a string using recursion, for 2 days now. I tried to write some pseudo-code, but i can't really implement it.

Pseudocode:

write a function that takes text as a parameter

set a counter, for each element

set a result, using key,value for each character in element

base case: if we only have 1 string, then return the character and string

else return function-1 until the last element is hit.

```
var tekst = "We have to count strings";

function countStrings(tekst) {
  var count = 0
  var result = {}

  if (count > tekst.lentgh) {
    count++
    return result
  } else {
    return countStrings(tekst-1) 
  }
}
console.log(countStrings(tekst))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this logic:

```js
var tekst = "We have to count strings";

function countStrings(tekst) {
    if (tekst.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1 + countStrings(tekst.substring(1));
}

console.log(countStrings(tekst))
```

The approach here is, at each step of the recursion, to return 1 plus whatever the length of the substring from the next character onwards is.  That is, we recurse down the input string, one character at a time, building out the length.  The base case here occurs when the input to `countStrings()` happens to be empty string.  In this case, we just return 0, and stop the recursive calls.

Comment: i see your code works, but this one counts the amount of string. not the amount characters and strings - but i might be able to do something with it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I decided to attempt this problem and this is what I came up with. Definitely a challenging problem so don't feel bad if you didn't get it:

```
var countStrings = function(tekst) {
    if (tekst.length === 0) return {};
  
    var obj = countStrings(tekst.slice(1));
  
    if (obj[tekst[0]]) {
        obj[tekst[0]] += 1;
    } else {
        obj[tekst[0]] = 1;
    }
  
    return obj;
};
```